# View inside UIStackView is not resizing with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I have this following screen:

[image]

All of the views are inside an `UIStackView`. The yellow view would be circular on runtime. My issue when I run an a smaller iPhone (5S), the `light blue` view which contains the `yellow view`, will not get smaller, so the `red and blue view` from the bottom will shrink. I want these two and the `green view` to have fixed width and the `light blue view` to adapt height.

But for some reason it doesn't. I am sure is because of the constraints I set to the `yellow view`. But I can't figure out which one is the problem.

Here are the `yellow view` constraints:

[image]

The constraints for the other views are:

1. Green view: height = 64
2. Red and blue view: height = 50

Much appreciate if someone could take some time to look over this constraints and help me understand how to make the light blue (and yellow) to change height when screen changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try lowering the Content Compression Resistance Priority (vertical) for the light blue and yellow views to be less than 750, and the Content Compression Resistance Priority (vertical) for the green, red and blue views to be higher than 750 (maybe even 1000 / required if that's the case?)

### UPDATE

I took a look at your project. Actually, the issue doesn't seem to be with your stack views, constraints, or the `DailyStatusViewController` at all.  Instead, the issue looks more related to the `MainViewController` which is embedding the Daily Status view inside a scroll view.  The scroll view is both clipping to bounds, and is placed behind another container view.  If you turn off clip to bounds on the scroll view, and move the container view below it to be *behind* it, you will see your stack views laid out correctly, but were just being clipped.

As to why they were clipped, keep in mind that your out stack view has a required height constraint of 300, while the scroll view it's being embedded in has a height constraint to 45% of the screen height. So on smaller screens, there is less than 300 points available to display the Daily Status view, and so it is being clipped. You probably want to remove the fixed height constraint from your outer stack view and instead constrain it to the edges of the root view.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that I already did this, with no effects.

Comment: @Kobe  Hmm...any chance you could post a link to your project, or a sample project with just that screen?

Comment: Its made with Swift 3, so it's that ok ?

Comment: I have added the project here, if you have some spare time to have a look: https://github.com/adrianstanciu24/stack-view-test.git

Comment: @Kobe  I think I found your issue:  updated my answer